# Reverse code using psych package and remove NA in R

Tags: r, psych

My dataset looks like this:

```
values<-c(1,1,NA,3)
acceptance<-c(1,4,NA,1)
diffusion<-c(2,2,3,NA)
attitudes<-c(2,4,4,NA)
df<-data.frame(values,acceptance,diffusion,attitudes)

values  acceptance  diffusion  attitudes

  1         1          2           2 
  1         4          2           4
  NA        NA         3           4
  3         1          NA          NA
```

I used to `psych` package to reverse code `values` and `acceptance` using this code:

```
keys <- c("values", "acceptance")
df2 <- reverse.code(keys = keys, items = df, mini = NULL, maxi = NULL)
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
Error in colMax + colMin : non-numeric argument to binary operator
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In FUN(newX[, i], ...) : no non-missing arguments, returning NA
2: In FUN(newX[, i], ...) : no non-missing arguments, returning NA
3: In FUN(newX[, i], ...) : no non-missing arguments, returning NA
4: In FUN(newX[, i], ...) : no non-missing arguments, returning NA
5: In FUN(newX[, i], ...) : no non-missing arguments, returning NA
6: In FUN(newX[, i], ...) : no non-missing arguments, returning NA
7: In FUN(newX[, i], ...) : no non-missing arguments, returning NA
8: In FUN(newX[, i], ...) : no non-missing arguments, returning NA
```

I thought I could just use `na.rm=T` but it doesn't seem to work with this code. Any idea on how to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It works without any error in `2.1.3` version of `psych`

```
reverse.code(keys, items = df, mini = NULL, maxi = NULL)
      values- acceptance- diffusion attitudes
[1,]       3           4         2         2
[2,]       3           1         2         4
[3,]      NA          NA         3         4
[4,]       1           4        NA        NA
```

Comment: That's odd. I have the 2.1.6 version of psych and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @n23 In the documentation, it says `keys -A vector of 1s and -1s. -1 implies reverse the item`

Comment: Works for me with version `2.1.6`

Comment: @user20650 Yeah, it seems to work on this dataset I created to ask the question. Not sure why it doesn't work when I apply it to my own even though they're the same. I am using df3$values_reversed = 5-df$values and that seems to work.

Comment: @n23; check your data are numeric. I can reproduce error if they are character e.g. in your example use `acceptance <- as.character(c(1,4,NA,1))`

Comment: @user20650 thanks for the suggestion! I did check using is.numeric and comes up as TRUE.

Comment: @n23; was that just the keys variables you checked? It seems that if even only one variable is character in df, even if not the keys, you get this error. Otherwise, will need to to try to create a reproducible example

Comment: @user20650 I do have other variables as character in my df! I have decided to just stick with the method I mentioned above. Thanks so much for your help!